# assign more than one function to a button using Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, gpio

am Francisco Olguin, graphic designer from Chile. I'm doing my final project at my university. At the moment I have assigned sounds to buttons using Python on a raspberrypi 3. Here is the code i use.

```
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
    import os
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 

    GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

    while True: 

    input_state = GPIO.input(4)
    if input_state == False:
    print('Tutorial') 
    os.system('killall mpg123')
    os.system('mpg123 -q audio1.mp3 &') 
    time.sleep(0.2)

    input_state = GPIO.input(5)
    if input_state == False:
    print('I Regíon')
    os.system('killall mpg123')
    os.system('mpg123 -q audio2.mp3 &')
    time.sleep(0.2)

    input_state = GPIO.input(6)
    if input_state == False:
    print('II Regíon')
    os.system('killall mpg123')
    os.system('mpg123 -q audio3.mp3 &')
    time.sleep(0.2)

    input_state = GPIO.input(7)
    if input_state == False:
    print('XI Regíon')
    os.system('killall mpg123')
    os.system('mpg123 -q audio4.mp3 &')
    time.sleep(0.2)

    input_state = GPIO.input(8)
    if input_state == False:
    print('X Regíon')
    os.system('killall mpg123')
    os.system('mpg123 -q audio5.mp3 &')
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

This assigns 5 audios to buttons that play when you press them. From here all good but here is my problem/question.
I have 5 buttons with assigned audios, so I want to know if it is possible to assign another 5 audios to the same buttons when pressing another button (I hope you understand). To explain this I have this image:

[image]

The idea is that by pressing the "1" button you can play the a1b1c1d1e1 sounds (corresponding to the 5 buttons assigned to the sounds)
presssing the "2" button you can play the a2b2c2d2e2 sounds and so on until the "5" button.

if anyone knows some way to be able to do that in an "easy" way would be great (I do not know much about python other than what I've already done)

Many thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english

Comment: You can pass a list directly to the `mpg123` command to play mp3s in order. Is there an issue with doing it that way?

Comment: Also, shouldn't `input_state` be True if a button was pushed for that pin or does pushing your button have other side effects on other input pins?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow what your asking, but I understand it as wanting to change the sound associated with all of the buttons when say number '1' is pressed, for example pressing '2' would assign sound 'a2' to button 'a'. To do this place a variable outside of your while loop that indicates what set of sounds should be used and an array for each of the 5 audio buttons that contains your desired set of sounds for that button. For example say you default to a1b1c1d1e1 then have something like this:

```
sound_index = 0 # corresponds to sound set 1

a_sound_files = ['a1.mp3', 'a2.mp3', ...]
...

while true:
    input_state = GPIO.input(4)
    if input_state == False:
        print('Tutorial') 
        os.system('killall mpg123')
        audio_file = a_sound_files[sound_index]
        os.system('mpg123 -q {file} &'.format(file=audio_file)) 
        time.sleep(0.2)
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Then just add the cases for your 5 new buttons and have them change the sound index accordingly.

**EDIT:**
The code is given below:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 

# I'm assuming 4 is 'a', 5 is 'b', and so on
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

# Let these be your new buttons where 11 = button 1,
# 12 = button 2, and so on
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

# Keeps track of which sound set to play
sound_index = 0 # corresponds to sound set 1

# These contain the set of sounds for each button
a_sound_files = ['a1.mp3', 'a2.mp3', ...]
b_sound_files = ['b1.mp3', 'b2.mp3', ...]
c_sound_files = ['c1.mp3', 'c2.mp3', ...]
d_sound_files = ['d1.mp3', 'd2.mp3', ...]
e_sound_files = ['e1.mp3', 'e2.mp3', ...]

while True: 
    input_state = GPIO.input(4)
    if input_state == False:
        print('Tutorial') 
        os.system('killall mpg123')
        audio_file = a_sound_files[sound_index]
        os.system('mpg123 -q {file} &'.format(file=audio_file)) 
    time.sleep(0.2)

    input_state = GPIO.input(5)
    if input_state == False:
        print('I Regíon')
        os.system('killall mpg123')
        audio_file = b_sound_files[sound_index]
        os.system('mpg123 -q {file} &'.format(file=audio_file)) 
    time.sleep(0.2)

    input_state = GPIO.input(6)
    if input_state == False:
        print('II Regíon')
        os.system('killall mpg123')
        audio_file = c_sound_files[sound_index]
        os.system('mpg123 -q {file} &'.format(file=audio_file)) 
    time.sleep(0.2)

    input_state = GPIO.input(7)
    if input_state == False:
        print('XI Regíon')
        os.system('killall mpg123')
        audio_file = d_sound_files[sound_index]
        os.system('mpg123 -q {file} &'.format(file=audio_file)) 
    time.sleep(0.2)

    input_state = GPIO.input(8)
    if input_state == False:
        print('X Regíon')
        os.system('killall mpg123')
        audio_file = e_sound_files[sound_index]
        os.system('mpg123 -q {file} &'.format(file=audio_file)) 
    time.sleep(0.2)

    # These are your buttons that change the sound set
    input_state = GPIO.input(11)
    if input_state == False:
        sound_index = 0
    time.sleep(0.2)

    input_state = GPIO.input(12)
    if input_state == False:
        sound_index = 1
    time.sleep(0.2)

    input_state = GPIO.input(13)
    if input_state == False:
        sound_index = 2
    time.sleep(0.2)

    input_state = GPIO.input(14)
    if input_state == False:
        sound_index = 3
    time.sleep(0.2)

    input_state = GPIO.input(15)
    if input_state == False:
        sound_index = 4
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

There are many solutions to this problem. Python is a fairly straight forward language so the syntax should not limit you once you have come up with a generic solution to your problem.

Comment: Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. I still do not understand at all since I do not understand much about python. Would there be a possibility to give me an example integrating this to the code I wrote above?, or would I have to change everything? Sorry for the question but I do not understand much about python: /